# "Duplex" Ef code first db operations

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an **`User`** class that have the following fields:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public ICollection<Event> AdminEvents { get; set; }
public ICollection<Event> SubscribedEvents { get; set; }
```

And my **`Event`** class looks like:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public ICollection<User> Subscribed { get; set; }
public User Admin { get; set; }
public int AdminId { get; set; }
```

OnModelCreating in my **`Context`**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.SubscribedEvents).WithMany(u => u.Subscribed);
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.AdminEvents).WithRequired(u => u.Admin).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

---

- The point here is that User can create an Event (`Event.Admin && Admin.Id`) and can be subscribed to others events (`User.SubscribedEvents && Event.Subscribed`)
- When i try to access `User.SubcribedEvents.ToList()` it throws the
  following error:

  Value cannot be null.Parameter name: source

  But inserting works, and the value goes into the right table:
  `**dbo.UserEvents**`.
- What's wrong with my entities design?. If you need more information
  to trace the trouble please ask. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navigation and collection properties (at least) should be virtual so they can be lazily initialized.